# Accessing method from other class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, class, methods

I have `Class1`, `Class2`, and `SubclassOfClass2`. I want to call method that is in `SubclassOfClass2` from `Class1`. I do:

```
Class2 *class = [[Class2 alloc] init];
[class someMethod];
```

But, as I guess, due to `alloc`, all variables values are being lost after that. Because:

At runtime `Class2` is being executed. It sets for example variable `float x = image.size.width`. And it returns correct value. Later, after for example user pressed button, `Class1` is being executed. After calling `someMethod` from `Class1` variable `x` returns `0.00000`. How to make it working so that variables values wouldn't be lost?

As I have been asked, here is my `someMethod` code:

```
-(void)someMethod {
NSLog(@"%f", x);
}
```

At run time that method returns `3200.00000` and when its called from `Class1` it returns `0.00000`. Variable `x` is declared in `Class2` and method `someMethod` is in `SubclassOfClass2`

---

Class1.h

```
@interface Class1

@end
```

Class1.m

```
#import "Class1.h"
#import "Class2.h"

@implementation Class1
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
Class2 *class = [[Class2 alloc] init];
[class someMethod];
}
@end
```

Class2.h

```
@interface Class2 {
 float x;
}
@end
```

Class2.m

```
#import "Class2.h"
#import "SubclassOfClass2.h"

@implementation Class2
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    x = 3200;
    [self someMethod];
    return self;
}
@end
```

SubclassOfClass2.h

```
#import "Class2.h"

@interface Class2 (subclass) {
}
-(void)someMethod;
@end
```

SubclassOfClass2.m

```
#import "SubclassOfClass2.h"
@implementation Class2 (subclass)
 -(void)someMethod {
   NSLog(@"%f", x);
 }
@end
```

Comment: I'm sorry, can you please try to rewrite your question so we can understand it.  What is "that method"?  Can we see its code?  Please fix the typo in line 1 of your code fragment (what is `class`).  If you want people to a answer your question, please put some effort into asking it.

Comment: In addition to @JeremyP comment please give more information on why you are creating a new instance of a supposedly "meta-class". It's look like you are not using the correct "meta-level" to achieve what your are trying to do.

Comment: Updated my question. And what is `meta-class` and `meta-level`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns 0.00000 because you're calling `init`.  That's a different method from `initWithCoder:`, which is the one that sets `x`.

(Other problems: have your classes inherit from NSObject as a base class and don't use `class` as a variable name...especially when it's not a class object.)

Comment: And how to fix it? How to make it working so that variables values wouldn't be lost. By the way, there is no difference if `x` is set in `initWithCoder` or anywhere else. Variable `x` is setted during runtime and it works all the time until running `Class1`.

Comment: No variable values are being lost.  You're simply not calling the method that sets them in the first place.  The fix is to set `x` inside some method that `Class1` actually calls, which in your example might be `- (id)init {
    x = 3200;
    return self;
}`.